# TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() > int()

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

I am trying the following code for deskewing an image but I am recieving error :

```
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() > int()
```

The bug is in the following line :

coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))

The full code is :

```py
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

image= cv2.imread('das.jpg',0)

gray = cv2.bitwise_not(image)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)

if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
else:
    angle=-angle
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h),flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
cv2.imwrite('a.jpg',rotated)
```

Comment: Please show [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It seems that `thresh` is a tuple and probably you expected something different

Comment: @rpoleski I have updated the code.

Comment: I've just googled it and [found](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) that `cv2.threshold()` returns a tuple. You probably should discard the first element of the tuple.

Comment: @rpoleski could you show me how the problem propagates to angle variable when i do so.

Comment: Instead of blindly trying different things in hope of finding something that works, look at the problem variable, `thresh`.  What is it?  Apparently it's a `tuple`. But a tuple of what?  Read the docs as well.  This is basics of debugging - you can't fix the problem until you understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally made it work **cv2.threshold** returns a tuple of 2 elements the first one is the optimum threshold value and the second is an array of the output image. So changing the bugged line to :

```
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh[1] > 0))
```

After this the same problem occurs with the angle variable which is also a tuple of 3 elements. The first element provides the centre of the rectangle, the second element provides height and width and the third element provides us with the rotation angle in a clockwise direction which we need. To get the angle into desired format we need to convert it to a list so it can be formatted.  Therefore the code needs to be changed to :

```
    angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)
    new_list=list(angle)

    if new_list[2] < -45:
      new_list[2] = -(90 + new_list[2])
    else:
      new_list[2]=-new_list[2]
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
     center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, new_list[2], 1.0)
```

The rest of the code remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh[1] > 0))
```

Comment: I have already tried that. It is still showing the same error but in a different line :
if angle < -45:
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int()

Comment: That's a different problem. I've just checked that `minAreaRect()` "Finds a rotated rectangle of the minimum area enclosing the input 2D point set." You're treating the output as some kind of angle, but it doesn't seem to be an angle.